# execution of a function with a specific environment variable

Tags: r, environment-variables

I apparently do not understand how to use environments, so maybe someone can help me. I want to eval those function in `sapply`, so they use `k = 1`.

```
fList <- list(function(x) k + 3, function(x) k + 4)
k <- 3
t <- sapply(1:2,
            function(x) {
               f <- fList[[x]]
               evalq(s <- f(1), list(k = 1))
               evalq(s <<- f(1), list(k = 1))
               s
             })
t
```

Comment: Change `list(function(x) k + 3, ...` to `list(function(k) k + 3, ...`, and change to `sapply(..., function(x) { f <- fList[[x]]; s <- f(1) })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in R use lexical scoping. This means they look for variable values in the environment where they were **defined**, not where they were run. You can change the environment of a function however. This is possible (not not necessarily recommended)

```
fList <- list(function(x) k + 3, function(x) k + 4)
k <- 3
t <- sapply(1:2,
            function(x) {
              f <- fList[[x]]
              env <- new.env(parent=baseenv())
              env$k <- 1
              environment(f) <- env
              s<-f(1)
              s <<- f(1)
              s
            })
t
# [1] 4 5
```

You could also use expressions rather than functions

```
eList <- expression( k + 3, k + 4)
k <- 3
t <- sapply(1:2,
            function(x) {
              e <- eList[[x]]
              s <- eval(e, list(k = 1))
              s <<- eval(e, list(k = 1))
              s
            })
t
```

But it would probably be better to not leave free variables in your function at all and explicitly pass parameters or an environment to that function.

Comment: or just use the environment within the anonymous function rather than creating a new environment; i.e. `environment(f) <- environment(); k <- 1; s <- f(x)`